# How to generate multiple div at random position inside a parent div using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

1. I am actually trying to create a game when someone hover on the gray area then it will ask if he wants to play if he confirm then random 5 div will appear in some different area of that parent div.
2. at first there should be only 1 big div. when someone will hover a mouse there will be option if he wants to play the game. then the big div will generate 5 small divs inside it. ( next i have delete if someone click small divs and need to track point, so its a small game for just my learning perpose
3. but i stuck here because i can't generate divs in random position. if you run my code you will see 3 divs verticaly appear when you confirm to play

```js
function hoverinside(x) {
    let answer = confirm("Do you want to play the game?");

    if (answer == true) {
        alert("Enjoy the game");
        
       myFunction();
    }
    else {
        alert("If you want to play just hover on the gray area again");
        location.reload();

    }
}




function myFunction() {
    
    var element = document.createElement('div');
    element.style.cssText = "width:55px; height:55px; background:green;";

    document.body.appendChild(element);

    var div1 = document.getElementById("square");
    div1.insertBefore(element, div1.childNodes[5])



    var element2 = document.createElement('div');
    element2.style.cssText = "width:55px; height:55px; background:yellow;"

    document.body.appendChild(element2);

    var div2 = document.getElementById("square");
    div2.insertBefore(element2, div2.childNodes[5])


    var element3 = document.createElement('div');
    element3.style.cssText = "width:55px; height:55px; background:red;";

    document.body.appendChild(element3);

    var div3 = document.getElementById("square");
    div3.insertBefore(element3, div3.childNodes[5])



}

function removediv1() {
    var element = document.getElementById("div2");
    element.classList.remove("div2");
  }
```

```css
h1 {
    font-style: bold;
    color: brown;
}
#square{
    height: 350px;
    width: 700px;
    background-color: rgb(170, 168, 168);
    border: brown;
    border-style: solid;
}
#square1{
    height: 35px;
    width: 70px;
    background-color: rgb(245, 10, 10);
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="gamejs.js"></script>
    <title>Game</title>
</head>
<body onload=OpenInNewtab(google.com)>
    <h1>Game:</h1>
    
    <p>we will create the game over here. no problem just wait and chill and play with us.we will create the game over here. no problem just wait and chill and play with us.</p>
    <h1>Points:</h1>
    <br>
    <div id="square" onmouseover="hoverinside(this)" >
         <div id="child1"> </div>
    </div> 

</body>
</html>
```

this is my code

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? Do you mean that the 5 `div`s will appear inside the parent div, but in a randomized location?

Comment: Hello, I have added my code. where i need to make change please mention if anyone can help thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

**Steps**

- Create a `child div`
- Add `id` to itnot necessay.
- For distinguishing, add different colors
- Make the `child div` as absolute
- Add random `left` & `right` position styling to `Child Div` (This will assure the randomness)

**Updated the code, so that child div be be confined inside parent div.**

##### You can refer to this codepen: https://codepen.io/hackhimanshu1024/pen/JjrjOjK

`Note`: I am not adding hover and deleting events. You can handle it as per your code.

---

*Note: Add other styles as per your requirements.*

```js
const parentBody = document.getElementById("root");
const btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
const btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
let i = 0, interval

function addDiv(cnt = 5) {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.id = 'div';
  div.style.top = `${Math.random() * 100}%`;
  div.style.left = `${Math.random() * 100}%`;
  div.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${Math.random() * 100},${Math.random() * 100},${Math.random() * 100})`;
  parentBody.appendChild(div);
  i++;
  if (i === cnt) clearInterval(interval);
}

function intervalDiv(){  
  i=0;
  interval = setInterval(addDiv, 1000);
}

function multipleDiv(){
  i=0;
  while(i<5){
    addDiv();
  }
}

btn1.addEventListener('click', intervalDiv);
btn2.addEventListener('click', multipleDiv);
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

body{
  height:100vh;
  max-height:100vh;
  max-width:100vw;
  padding: 100px;
}

#root{
  height:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  position: relative;
}

#btn1, #btn2{
  position:relative;
  z-index:200;
}

#div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id="root">
    <button id="btn1">CLICK ME on Interval</button>
    <button id="btn2">CLICK ME for 5 times</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is not actually working for my project

Comment: This is the code for creating `cnt` number of divs at random position at an `interval` of `1sec`. I can't understand the query. Can you explain it more?

Comment: Yes sure. at first there should be only 1 big div. when someone will hover a mouse there will be option if he wants to play the game. then the big div will generate 5 small divs inside it. ( next i have delete if someone click small divs and need to track point, so its a small game for just my learning perpose)

Comment: but i stuck here because i can't generate divs in random position. if you run my code you will see 3 divs verticaly appear when you confirm to play

Comment: perhaps you need `position: relative`, instead of `absolute`. then you could replace the `div.style.[top/left] = `Math.random() * 100 + "%"` with `div.style.[top/left] = `Math.random * (parentBody.offset[Width/Height] / 2)`